# In what universe is a potential duplicate question not a good fit for Q&A?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

[Choosing the right one for self-defense purpose?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/choosing-the-right-one-for-self-defense-purpose)

David closed it on both or either grounds, but that's completely illogical. If it's possibly a duplicate, then how could it not be a good fit?

Answer (score 1):

Closing a question as a duplicate means the question is the essentially the same as another. The question that was closed is not fundamentally different than [the other question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/159/which-martial-arts-focus-on-self-defense) that had been mentioned in the comments already.

Any new answers on that question are likely to be applicable to the other and would best belong there under one question rather than have the continual possibility of people asking the same question over and over (good *or* bad). If a new user does take the time to read through the other established question that is the same as his, then he may have already found his answer.

However, as David H. Clements had already stated in his answer, the question can be reopened provided that it is edited to ask something different enough from the older question and goes further beyond what has already been covered.

Comment: Yes, but if it's a duplicate of an open question, that means that the question is inherently a good fit. It can't both be a duplicate and not a good fit at the same time, the two are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

If I had seen that question before it got closed, I would have cast a NARQ close vote as well. It is wide open, very few constraints, and likely to lead to extensive discussion. The faults with the question are clear enough that David could safely pre-empt the community moderation. It's not a bad question to ask and the OP didn't know any better, the question simply needs some tuning and lovin'.

**The way the question currently stands**, it doesn't matter that the guy is in Singapore, the locality is immaterial to a correct answer. The locality simply gives him options to pursue the answer. The fact he is in Singapore doesn't make the question okay, it still needs changing.

Stop being obstinate, get in there and edit the question if you want it reopened. That is the way the SE sites work. If correctly edited and reopened the answer to that question should still be of good value in several years time, unlike the answers you will encounter on other sites. That is exactly what the SE network is striving for with the rules/guidelines they have - **quality questions** and **quality answers**. If you do answer the question try to avoid making your answer too localised (your answer won't be of any value to others with similar requirements but in a totally different location).

Comment: Agreed. It can be a good question with editing. Until then it's not a question. That's OK.

Comment: You couldn't be more wrong that the location is immaterial to the answer.

Comment: Furthermore, on other SE sites, questions are left open for a couple days, to give the person asking the question an opportunity to change it and make it a good question, that's a good standard and it's one that the moderators here should follow.

Comment: @Robin have you ever noticed that you are the only one running around telling everybody else that they couldn't be more wrong? Read my answer: **The way the question currently stands**. The guy wants suggestions based on physical parameters, not location. By all means introduce some local options that fit the overall answer, but don't make the local options the only part of the answer, otherwise the answer is no good to someone in Sydney, Auckland, Toronto, New York, etc. Does that help make my answer clearer?

Comment: @Robin you should also remember that we are trying to help here, hence the discourse. Don't go off half cocked all the time and doubt people's integrity or intellectual honesty. That's exactly the sort of behaviour that we are trying to avoid here - MA sites are no good when people fly off the handle about things.

Comment: @slugster that's because you are wrong. facts are facts. there's a fact that the moderation policies of david and matt are driving new members away. it's also a fact that david and matt are far quicker to close questions on MA.SE than on other stack exchange sites. they're not doing their jobs properly

Comment: and closing questions based on your own ignorance is really not a good way of going about it.

Comment: MA sites are no good when you've got rogue mods

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good fit if it is an exact duplicate of another question, and there's nothing in the question at the moment that distinguishes it from the other question asked.

That's standard to Stack Exchange's model: If it is an exact duplicate, it is going to get closed.  If you believe it is not an exact duplicate, please use the edit feature to change the scope appropriately.

There are several fundamental problems with the question as it stands now. One is it is likely to elicit polling and extended debate (not constructive), the second is that it is overly broad and vague the way it is now (hence the close reason that's specified, and I only get to specify one), the third is that it looks a *lot* like another question that has already been asked.

If these issues are fixed, it is easy to reopen, but the proper order should be Close->Fix->Reopen, not "Leave open with people answering a changing question that's not a great fit as it currently stands."

Comment: It wasn't an exact duplicate, if it were, you wouldn't be unsure if it's a duplicate. Drawing further information out could have determined if it were a different question, but the asker hasn't been on MA.SE since you closed the question, so we're likely never going to get any further in figuring that out.

Comment: Fix it and it can be reopened, not a big deal

Comment: yes it is, and i've already addressed why

Answer (score -2):

From the FAQ about types of questions to ask

> Evaluating and choosing martial arts given specific criteria (e.g. grappling, high kicks, self-defense, etc.)

That's about as good a fit as it gets for this site. It was also more specific than the generic question that had been asked about SD.

The mods should really get in the habit of reading the FAQ line by line, from the top, not the bottom, before closing questions.